# Why does my VLC window show weird fonts?

Tags: 16.04, vlc, window, japanese

So, I have Japanese language installed on Ubuntu (even though it's not activated so I assume I have the fonts). When I play a file which is named "百物語の幽霊.mp3", it opens VLC but the window title is messed up (see screenshot). 
[image: Window Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Tools >> Preference
[image]

Set Subtitle Language >> Default Encoding to

System codeset or Universal (UTF-8)

In my case, VLC 2.2.2 it works fine.

Best Regards,